# ExtJS Grid Selection Model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a ExtJS grid with a store mapped to it.

The JSON response for the store contains 20 fields, but I have mapped only 10 fields in the store. Is it possible for me to obtain the other 10 fields without me having to map them in the store or is it necessary for me to map all the fields to the store. Doing this on row select event of the grid. As for the code, I am able to create the grid, map the store, fire the event and even get the record for the selected row with the mapped 10 field.

Any suggestions ??

As requested by Shekhar :

> Store definition

```
Ext.define('gdoc.store.PrintPaperStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'PrintPaperStore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'urlToRetrieveTheJSON',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'root'
                }
            },
            fields: [{
                    mapping: 'value',
                    name: 'value'
                },
                {
                    mapping: 'display',
                    name: 'display'
                }
            ]
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

> The JSON Response :

```
{
     "root": [{
         "value": "COATED115",
         "display": "Coated recycled paper (115gms)",
         "description": "Good quality",
         "extra": "EXTRA INFO"
     }, {
         "value": "COATED135",
         "display": "Coated recycled paper (135gms)",
         "description": "Good quality"
     }, {
         "value": "OFFSET",
         "display": "Offset recycled paper (80gms)",
         "description": "Good quality",
         "extra": "EXTRA INFO"
     }, {
         "value": "OTHER",
         "display": "Other paper (client to order)",
         "description": "Good quality",
         "extra": "EXTRA INFO"
     }]
 }
```

As you can see I have mapped only `value` and `display` from the `JSON` response in the `store`.

Is it possible for me to retrieve values of `description` and `extra` without me having to map them in the `store`.

Comment: Can you show ur store's code?

Comment: Please include your code in your question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the .raw property on the model, which will contain the raw JSON from the reader.

Answer (score 1):

No. The model, or store, must set all the fields you want to have available from the JSON data.

I'm confused as to why you don't want to map the extra fields? It's it purely time saving and hoping there was a quicker way to get access to the data? Or are you expecting the fields names to be dynamic?

If it's the dynamic reason, take a look at this post for a solution. [Dynamic model with ExtJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751289/dynamic-model-with-extjs-4)

Comment: Time saving is one of the things yes. But yeah the field names change dynamically and as the fields I am working with is more than 20 I was wondering if there might be another way to access it.

Comment: I added a link which shows how to generate a model/store on the fly and update the columns of a grid. So using that you should be able to get the outcome you want.