# Extjs4 How to change a Model dynamically?

Tags: extjs, model

I use Extjs4 and MVC. I would like to change my Model's fields dynamically...
Something like adding a variable number of fields... Any suggests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Model with ExtJS 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751289/dynamic-model-with-extjs-4)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you be a bit more specific? And also what version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: Extjs4, for example I have a model with 3 field... I want extend it with other six field...

Comment: This question should have never been closed as not a real question!! It is a perfectly legitimate question.  Don't vote to close just because you don't understand whats being asked.  That said, it is duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `model.setFields(fieldsArray)` function, shown [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-setFields) in the API. This method replaces all existing fields on the model with whatever new fields you include in the argument. There is not a static `getFields` method to capture the existing fields so as not to overwrite them but it is easy enough to get them using `model.prototype.fields`.

I did this recently to attach dynamic permission setting fields to a "User" model before I loaded the user. Here's an example:

```
Ext.define('myApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models: [
        'User',
    ],

    stores: [
        'CurrentUser', // <-- this is not autoLoad: true
        'PermissionRef', // <-- this is autoLoad: true
    ],

    views: ['MainPanel'],

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        // when the PermissionRef store loads 
        // use the data to update the user model
        me.getPermissionRefStore().on('load', function(store, records) {
            var userModel = me.getUserModel(),
                fields = userModel.prototype.fields.getRange();
                // ^^^ this prototype function gets the original fields 
                // defined in myApp.model.User

            // add the new permission fields to the fields array
            Ext.each(records, function(permission) {
                fields.push({
                    name: permission.get('name'), 
                    type: 'bool'
                });
            });

            // update the user model with ALL the fields
            userModel.setFields(fields);

            // NOW load the current user with the permission data
            // (defined in a Java session attribute for me)
            me.getCurrentUserStore().load();

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I just noticed that this is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751289/dynamic-model-with-extjs-4) after I answered it. I gave the exact same answer there...